# Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise with ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

After some hours spent searching the web for implementation of Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise with ASP.NET CORE 3.1, I must, unfortunately, admit that I was not able to find anything I could use in my project.
I've read the docs following the [official site](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise), but in the end, I'm still stucking for a clean implementation.

In [ASP.NET Monsters](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2020/11/Processing-Google-reCaptcha-Tokens-in-ASP-NET-Core/) there is an example, but targeting reCAPTCHA V3 and not reCAPTCHA enterprise.

There is also a nice post here [Google ReCaptcha v3 server-side validation using ASP.NET Core 5.0](https://dev.to/spencer741/google-recaptcha-v3-server-side-validation-using-asp-net-core-5-0-3hfb), but again on reCAPTCHA V3.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to find details on this?

Comment: not yet. I search on google, SO and so on regularly, but all posts are targeting V3 and not the Enterprise version

Comment: i fixed mine, all working now

Comment: Hi Gillardo, it would be great if you could share your solution. Many thanks in advance. I'm sure, this would help a lot of other developer struggling with the Enterprise version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for me i needed to implement google recapthca with dotnet 5 using an angular front end.  I am sure you can replace the angular front end with the native javascript instead, but this took me hours of investigating so hopefully it will help people.

First i had to enable reCAPTCHA Enterprise, to do this i went to https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/ and then clicked on the "go to console" button.  This took me to my Google Cloud Platform. From here i needed to create a key, fill in the options and save. This key will be referred to as your SITE_KEY.

-- IF YOU ARE USING ANGULAR, READ THIS, ELSE SKIP THIS STEP AND IMPLEMENT IT YOURSELF

On the client i used ng-recaptcha, you can find it [here](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha)

To implement this component, i added this import to my app.module.ts

```
import { RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY } from 'ng-recaptcha';
```

and this to the providers section

```
      {
          provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY,
          useValue: SITE_KEY_GOES_HERE
      }
```

On my component, when the submit button is pressed, i used the `ReCaptchaV3Service` from the library above.  My code looks like this

```
this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(YOUR_ACTION_NAME).subscribe((recaptchaResponse) => {
    // now call your api on the server and make sure you pass the recaptchaResponse string to your method
    });
```

The text `YOUR_ACTION_NAME` is the name of the action you are doing.  In my case i passed `'forgotPassword'` as this parameter.

-- END OF ANGULAR PART

Now on the server, first i included this into my project

```
<PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1" Version="1.2.0" />
```

Once included in my service, i found it easier to create a service in my code, which is then injected.  I also created a basic options class, which is injected into my service, it can be injected into other places if needed.

RecaptchaOptions.cs

```
    public class RecaptchaOptions
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        public string PrivateKeyId { get; set; }

        public string PrivateKey { get; set; }

        public string ClientEmail { get; set; }

        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public string SiteKey { get { return YOUR_SITE_KEY; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// 0.1 is worst (probably a bot), 0.9 is best (probably human)
        /// </summary>
        public float ExceptedScore { get { return (float)0.7; } }
    }
```

Some of these values are not used, but i have added them for the future, encase i do use them.

Then i have created my service, which looks like so (i have created an interface for injecting and testing)

IRecaptchaService.cs

```
public interface IRecaptchaService
{
    Task<bool> VerifyAsync(string recaptchaResponse, string expectedAction);
}
```

RecaptchaService.cs

```
public class RecaptchaService : IRecaptchaService
{
    #region IRecaptchaService

    /// <summary>
    /// Check our recaptcha
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recaptchaResponse">The response from the client</param>
    /// <param name="expectedAction">The action that we are expecting</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<bool> VerifyAsync(string recaptchaResponse, string expectedAction)
    {
        // initialize request argument(s)
        var createAssessmentRequest = new CreateAssessmentRequest
        {
            ParentAsProjectName = ProjectName.FromProject(_recaptchaOptions.ProjectId),
            Assessment = new Assessment()
            {
                Event = new Event()
                {
                    SiteKey = _recaptchaOptions.SiteKey,
                    Token = recaptchaResponse
                }
            },
        };

        // client
        var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        var client = RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient.Create();

        // Make the request
        try
        {
            var response = await client.CreateAssessmentAsync(createAssessmentRequest, cancellationToken);

            return response.TokenProperties.Valid && response.TokenProperties.Action.Equals(expectedAction) && response.RiskAnalysis?.Score >= _recaptchaOptions.ExceptedScore;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return false;
        }

    }

    #endregion

    private RecaptchaOptions _recaptchaOptions;

    public RecaptchaService(RecaptchaOptions recaptchaOptions)
    {
        _recaptchaOptions = recaptchaOptions;
    }
}
```

Now my api endpoint, i inject this service and call it. Here is an example API method that calls the recaptchaService.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPasswordAsync([FromBody] ForgotPasswordModel model)
{
    // check our recaptchaResponse
    var verified = await _recaptchaService.VerifyAsync(model.RecaptchaResponse, "forgotPassword");

    if (!verified)
        throw new ApplicationException("Recaptcha failed, please try again");

    // successful, carry on
}
```

Hope this helps everyone, if there are any questions, please ask and i will edit this and update it with anything i have missed.

Comment: How do you deal with The Application Default Credentials are not available?

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry for my late reply. For credentials you have to go into Google Cloud Platform -> APIs & Services -> Credentials. From there you can create your Credentials. After that yuo will be able to download them as a json file. I've stored these information in my secrets.json (during development) and in Azure KeyVault Secrets for production.

Comment: To use the credentials you have to go for RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClientBuilder().

Comment: `var credentials = new  Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "type" , Type },
    { "project_id" , ProjectId},
    { "private_key_id" , PrivateKeyId},
    { "private_key" , PrivateKey},
    { "client_email" , ClientEmail},
    { "client_id" , ClientId},
    { "auth_uri" , Auth_uri},
    { "token_uri" , Token_uri},
    { "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" , Auth_provider_x509_cert_url},
    { "client_x509_cert_url" , Client_x509_cert_url}
};`

Comment: `string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials, Formatting.Indented);
var jsonCredentials = jsonstring;

RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClientBuilder clientBuilder = new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClientBuilder() {};
clientBuilder.JsonCredentials = jsonCredentials;

var client = clientBuilder.Build();`